# Probability/combinatorics - cards with different color fronts and backs

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I've rephrased my problem to read a bit more like a homework question in the hope that doing so might make it easier to interpret.

I have 10 cards. The color of the front of the card is either pink or purple. The color of the back of the card is orange, blue, or red. Here’s what I know:

- 7 of the cards have pink fronts, 3 have purple fronts
- 5 of the cards have orange backs, 1 has a blue back, and 4 have red backs
- Cards with a purple front can not have a red back

What are the conditional probabilities for the backs given what’s on the front? That is:

1. Given that a card has a pink front, what are the probabilities that its back is orange/blue/red?
2. Given that a card has a purple front, what are the probabilities that its back is orange/blue? (I know it can’t be red from the info above.)

Perhaps it's easier to think of the question as "if you're handed a new card with a pink (or purple) front, what are the odds that the back is orange/blue/red given that the new card follows the same probability distribution as the 10 old cards?"

I've wandered down a few routes trying to figure out the solution, including Bayes theorem and some version of inclusion/exclusion, but I can't quite figure out the right path. Thanks for the help!

Edited to add some work:
The conditional probabilities for cards with purple fronts are easy: 1/6 will have a blue back, and 5/6 will have an orange back. Clearly I'm missing something with the pink cards though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For convenience, let me introduce the following notation:

$\mathbb{E}[X]$ denotes the [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) of $X$. Pi, Pu, O, B, R denote the number of cards of color Pink, Purple, Orange, Blue, Red respectively. $[X,Y]$ denotes the number of cards with both properties $X$ and $Y$.

From your edit, I get that $\mathbb{E}[Pu, B]=3*\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{2}$. The remaining $\frac{1}{2}$ blue card is Pink, so the probability of a pink card being blue is $\frac{1}{2\times7}=\frac{1}{14}$. Similarly, the probability of a pink card being orange is $\frac{5}{14}$ and the probability of a pink card being red is $\frac{4}{7}$.

Another way to approach this problem would be to note that it is easy to find the probability of a pink card being red, and the rest must be divided in the ratio $5:1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I started to write out a "what if" scenario, but I think it ventures too far afield from my original question and probably warrants a new question of its own.